# How to prevent bind dynamic updates from changing original zone file?

Tags: bind

I am using a certbot DNS plugin to issue Let's Encrypt certificates. Certbot uses dynamic DNS updates to add a `TXT` record for verification. Bind creates a `.jnl` file for the zone. This `TXT` record only exist for 30 seconds then is removed by certbot. When the process is done, everything is supposed to be back to normal.

The side effect is bind is over writing my original zone file (owned by `root`) and saving it as owned by `named`. Plus the contents of the zone file are completely reformatted in a way i do not like.

Is there anyway to prevent bind from trying to change the original zone file? Any way to tell bind this dynamic update is temporary, hold only in memory or something?

And a side, but not as important, question. How is it bind gives permission denied errors if it can't save the `.jnl` file without `named` ownership, but it can easily over write a zone file owned by `root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you use dynamic DNS you shouldn't expect your zonefile to be in any specific format and let bind manage it. Which is why you have the `rndc` commands `freeze` and `thaw`.

In your situation you should split concerns. Create `_acme-challenge` in your zone, as a `CNAME` to point it to another zone.
Then this zone can be free of dynamic updates and you can have your zonefile the way you like.

In the other zone, you enable dynamic updates and make sure `TXT` records are added there.

> but it can easily over write a zone file owned by root?

The permissions to edit (including delete) a file depends on the directory ownership/permissions in which the file is, not the ones on the file itself. Imagine a directory begin one file whose content is the list of files in it...

Comment: Although it is a creative solution with the CNAME it wont work for my purpose with certbot. To get certbot to update the temp zone, it would be making a cert for the temp zone and not the zone with the CNAME. But i will give you the answer for the effort as it might help someone else not trying to do this with certbot.

Comment: " it would be making a cert for the temp zone and not the zone with the CNAME." No. The CNAME trick is used by a lot of people, exactly for those kind of needs. See this example among others: https://www.heelpbook.net/2021/getting-lets-encrypt-certificate-using-dns-01-challenge-with-acme-dns-certbot-joohoi-or-acme-sh/ ; the CNAME is resolved at validation time by the CA, but the certificate will be for the zone name where the CNAME is. There is no urgency also to validate answers, you can wait for others to come too before deciding...